# Inequalities stated in the solution for Brezis Exercise 5.2

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Here are two inequalities stated in the solution given by Brezis for Exercise 5.2 and I am not seeing why this is true:
[image]

I know that when $p < 2$, we have $\frac{2}{p} > 1$ and hence we have
$$
2(\alpha + \beta)^{\frac{2}{p}} > \alpha^{\frac{2}{p}} + \beta^{\frac{2}{p}}
$$
as $\alpha^{\frac{2}{p}} < (\alpha + \beta)^{\frac{2}{p}}$ and $\beta^{\frac{2}{p}} < (\alpha + \beta)^{\frac{2}{p}}$. However, this does not seem to be the way to see these two inequalities as there are no constant factors presented here. Moreover, I have no idea how the second inequality is true knowing $\frac{2}{p} < 1$. It probably has to do with the convexity/concavity of the function $|x|^p$ when $p > 1$ and $p < 1$. However, I do not see how to justify this.

**Update:**

Here is another proof on top of the accepted answer:

We first show that
$$(\alpha + \beta)^{\frac{2}{p}} > \alpha^{\frac{2}{p}} + \beta^{\frac{2}{p}}$$ for $\alpha, \beta > 0$ if $p < 2$. In particular, we have $\frac{2}{p} > 1$. Equivalently, we wish to show that
$$
1 > \left(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta}\right)^{\frac{p}{2}} + \left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta}\right)^{\frac{p}{2}}.
$$
Equivalently, this is the same as showing the following statement:
If $x, y \in \mathbf{R}$, $x + y = 1$, $0 < x, y < 1$ and $r > 1$, then
$$
x^r + y^r < 1.
$$
To see this, simply note that we have $x < 1$ and $r > 1$. Therefore, we have $x^r < x$. Moreover, we have $y < 1$ and $r > 1$. Therefore, we also have $y^r < y$. This implies that we have
$$
x^r + y^r < x + y = 1.
$$
This shows the first inequality. Now to show the second inequality,  for the same reason as above, it is sufficient to show the statement: If $x, y \in \mathbf{R}$, $x + y = 1$, $0 < x, y < 1$ and $r < 1$, then
$$
x^r + y^r > 1.
$$
Now since $0 < x < 1$ and $r < 1$, we have $x^r > x$. Similarly, since $0 < y < 1$ and $r < 1$, we have $y^r > y$. Therefore, we have
$$
x^r + y^r > x + y = 1.
$$
Therefore, we are done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $q:=2/p$, then the inequalities are
$$
(a+b)^q<a^q+b^q, \qquad q<1,
$$
and
$$
(a+b)^q>a^q+b^q,\qquad q>1.
$$
This is not concavity/convexity (with those properties you can get the reverse inequalities, with a constant depending on $q$). Instead divide by $b^q$ and look at the function
$$
f(a):= (1+a)^q-a^q-1, \qquad a>0.
$$
Notice that
$$
f'(a)= q(1+a)^{q-1} -qa^{q-1},
$$
which never vanishes, so $f$ is (strictly) increasing when $q>1$ and decreasing when $q<1$. Since $\lim_{a\to0^+} f(a)=0$, your inequalities follow.